# How to find all possible tic tac toe board layouts in python?

Tags: python, html, loops, recursion, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to figure out all the possible board layouts for tic-tac-toe.
And then adding them to a html template.
My code is at the bottom.
I made about five different versions using recursion, iteration, both.
But they all fail for some reason.
Be it stack overflows, skipping layouts, or mysteriously crashing none of them run as intended.
If someone knows please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
After about then hours I'm ready to give up.

If someone wonders why I'm doing such a weird thing I needed to make tic-tac-toe with just html and css. And this was the only way I could think of.
Thank you, thank you, thank you.

```
import itertools
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

templateFile = open('template.html','r')
template = templateFile.read()
templateFile.close()

def hasWon(row):
    for player in ['x','o']:
        if (row[0] == player) & (row[1] == player) & (row[2] == player):
            return [True,player]
        if (row[3] == player) & (row[4] == player) & (row[5] == player):
            return [True,player]
        if (row[6] == player) & (row[7] == player) & (row[8] == player):
            return [True,player]

        if (row[0] == player) & (row[3] == player) & (row[6] == player):
            return [True,player]
        if (row[1] == player) & (row[4] == player) & (row[7] == player):
            return [True,player]
        if (row[2] == player) & (row[5] == player) & (row[8] == player):
            return [True,player]

    return [False,player]


def getTurn(turnN):
    if turnN % 2 == 0:
        return 'o'
    else:
        return 'x'



def doPages(row, turnN):
    global template
    curpage = template
    print "row:" + ''.join(row)
    for i in range(1,10):
        tempRow = row
        if row[i-1] == '-': #Cell is empty
            tempRow[i-1] = getTurn(turnN)
            print "tr: %s, turnN %d, i: %d" % (''.join(tempRow),turnN,i)
            curpage = curpage.replace('(page'+str(i)+')', ''.join(tempRow)+'.html')
            #doPages(tempRow, turnN+1)

        if row[i-1] == 'x': #Cell is full. Invalid
            curpage = curpage.replace('(page'+str(i)+')', '')
            curpage = curpage.replace('(style'+str(i)+')', 'background-color:red;')
        if row[i-1] == 'o': #Cell is full. Invalid
            curpage = curpage.replace('(page'+str(i)+')', '')
            curpage = curpage.replace('(style'+str(i)+')', 'background-color:blue;')

        doPages(tempRow, turnN+1)

    curpage = curpage.replace('(turn)', 'Turn: %d (%s)' % (turnN, getTurn(turnN)))

    if hasWon(row)[0]:
         curpage = curpage.replace('<!--won-->', '<h1>%s has won</h1>' % hasWon(row)[1])

    page = open('game/'+''.join(row)+'.html','w+')
    page.write(curpage)
    page.close()
    return


doPages(list(['-'] * 9),0)
print "Done"
```

P.S. if I need to post more data just say, and I'll put it all on github or something.

EDIT:
I got the tip to use itertools.
I did and here is the code.
But while this code works and generates strings as "oo-oxxx--" it doesn't make this one "ooxoxxx--".
And I can't for the life of me figure out why it does this.
Here is a striped down version that should produce all the boards.
Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
import itertools

def getTurn(turnN):
    if turnN % 2 == 0:
        return 'o'
    else:
        return 'x'

def hasValidAmount(row, turnNum):
    #aantal moet samen turn - 1 zijn
    #als turn even x is 1/2 turn en is o x -1
    #als turn oneven x en o is 1/2 turn -1 en
    x = row.count('x')
    o = row.count('o')
    if (turnNum % 2) == 0:
        if ((x / 2) == turnNum) & (o == (x - 1)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        if (x == (turnNum-1) / 2) & (o == x):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def hasWon(row):
    for player in ['x','o']:
        if (row[0] == player) & (row[1] == player) & (row[2] == player):
            return [True,player]
        if (row[3] == player) & (row[4] == player) & (row[5] == player):
            return [True,player]
        if (row[6] == player) & (row[7] == player) & (row[8] == player):
            return [True,player]

        if (row[0] == player) & (row[3] == player) & (row[6] == player):
            return [True,player]
        if (row[1] == player) & (row[4] == player) & (row[7] == player):
            return [True,player]
        if (row[2] == player) & (row[5] == player) & (row[8] == player):
            return [True,player]

    return [False,player]

def work():
    for i in itertools.product('-xo',repeat=9):
        row = list(i)

        turnNum = 10 - row.count('-')
        turn = getTurn(turnNum)

        if hasValidAmount(row, turnNum) == False:
            continue

        print ''.join(row)

        winner = '-'
        if hasWon(row)[0]:
             print '%s has won.' % hasWon(row)[1]

        for pageI in range(1,10):
            if row[pageI-1] == '-':
                tempRowList = list(i)
                tempRowList[pageI-1] = turn
                print ''.join(tempRowList)

work()
print "Done"
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand most of the HTML component of your question. But if you're just looking for a way to get all possible lists of length 9 that contain an x, o, or hyphen, you can do `allPossibleBoards = list(itertools.product("xo-", repeat=9))`

Comment: Are you trying to make something like this? http://lea.verou.me/2011/06/pure-css-tic-tac-toe/

Answer (score 1):

To make all possible full boards you could do

```
import itertools
player = ['O', 'X']
itertools.product(player, repeat = 9)
```

Then use a list comprehension to shape those each into 3x3 boards

```
[[i[0:3],i[3:6],i[6:10]] for i in itertools.product(player, repeat = 9)]
```

Result

```
[[('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O')],
 [('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'O'), ('O', 'O', 'X')],
 ... etc]
```

Standing issues:

1. It is possible (and likely) the game will be over before the board is completely full
2. You do not know the order in which the moves were done, so if there are two "winners" you don't know who won first
3. The above method is brute force, you will notice that not all boards are valid. The rules of tic-tac-toe say that each player takes turns. So boards with all 'O', for example are not possible.

The above being said, you should sit down and try to think of a more clever way to do this. Brute forcing has a number of problems, only some of which are listed. You'll have to take into account incomplete boards and the order of moves.

Comment: I think the implication in the question is that, in addition to generating all boards, it needs to be done in such a way that you can associate each state with all its possible child states, so that you can make a kind of "choose your own adventure" directory structure. So just generating all board states in sorted order isn't sufficient.